# How to simplify the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a for loop to generate a regular pattern image. please share on how to simplify the for loop with less lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m, n = 100, 100

grid_img = np.zeros([m,n])
x = np.linspace(0, 1, m)
y = np.linspace(0, 1, n)

for i in range(np.size(x)):
    for j in range(np.size(y)):
        xi = i*np.pi/4
        yi = j*np.pi/4

        grid_img[i][j] = np.sin(xi)+np.sin(yi)

grid_img[grid_img<1.5] = 0
```

Comment: Why does it need simplyfying? It's only three lines, you can reduce the line count, but it wont simplify it.

Comment: It seems like you had an assignment and want us to solve it for you :/
as @Bernhard said, there is very little to simplify here. Less lines doesn't always means more efficient and if you are concern with efficiency then your code as slightly bigger problem than having too many lines. I give you a hint: `xi = i*np.pi/4` cab be calculated less times. well actually also `np.pi/4` can be calculated only once, but you will need an extra line... see?

Comment: I used like following without "for". It worked before. I am not sure it is correct form. 
#B = 200 by 200 matrix
''' A_mat = (200, 200)
dx, dy = 0.1, 0.1 
x = np.linspace(-100, 99, 200)
y = np.linspace(-100, 99, 200)
A = np.zeros(A_mat, dtype=np.float64)
A = ((x*dx)+(y*dy))*B '''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace both `for` loops entirely with one line of list comprehension, but that would compromise readability.

```py
li = [ [ np.sin(i*np.pi/4) + np.sin(j*np.pi/4) for j in range(np.size(y)) ] for i in range(np.size(x)) ]
```

That will create a 2D Python list. Then you might want to change it to a numpy array for your `<1.5` condition:

```py
grid_img = np.array(li)
grid_img[grid_img<1.5] = 0
```